# Jquery .keyup on a dynamically added textfield

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, drupal

How to add keyup event for dynamically added textfield.i am developing web application in drupal.when i tried to use "live",Menu's are not working

```
$('input[id$="-code"], input[id$="-case"], input[id$="-vehicle-no"]')
.live('keyup', function(e){
   $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});
```

Comment: What do you mean with "not working"? You should add all relevant information when asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save the mess in the code add a class to the input field you are adding dynamically so that it will be easy for you. Anyways using live will work. Check out this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/QugQw/1/

Comment: @swordfish..in my case after "AddRow" button click,itcreates a row with four textfields.Among that "vehicle no" textfield is there.For only that particular textfield i want to add this event.How can i customize ur code according to that..

Comment: @user731060: Just include `class="b"` in the field you wish to have the keyup event attached to.

Comment: @user731060 just give a class to the field you want the event raised.

Answer (score 0):

"*@swordfish..in my case after "AddRow" button click,itcreates a row with four textfields.Among that "vehicle no" textfield is there.For only that particular textfield i want to add this event.How can i customize ur code according to that..*"

Sounds like you are creating new rows containing the fields you are wanting to attach the keyup event to. If so, then you may have more than one element on the same page with the same ID. A big no-no.

Instead, as **swordfish** has suggested, add a class to the fields you wish to attach the keyup event to (using that class in the jQuery selector), and drop the id attribute, using just the name attribute instead (but not using the name attribute for the jQuery selector - you won't need it).

Comment: id of vehicle_no textfield will be diffrent on each row

Comment: Good point. But the ID attribute is not really necessary anyway. You can use the name attribute instead and avoid the risk.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in another way also. Though it will violate "Don't Repeat Yourself". Refer to this section in jquery FAQs, [problem with dynamically created elements](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Why_do_my_events_stop_working_after_an_AJAX_request.3F). Instead of using live, just use .keyup() with the selector. You declare these binding again below the code where the elements are dynamically created. Use the below somewhere in the code inside $(document).ready() method.

```
$('input[id$="-code"], input[id$="-case"], input[id$="-vehicle-no"]')
.keyup(function(e){
$(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});
```

And below the code where you dynamically create those elements put the below.

```
$('input[id$="-code"], input[id$="-case"], input[id$="-vehicle-no"]')
.unbind('keyup').keyup(function(e){
$(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});
```

If other things are fine, it should work. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

For new elements on JQuery you use live function. But if you are using Drupal you must use behaviors.
I really don't understand exactly your problem, but I read that you try to use live, so I think this could help http://drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors